# In which case do we need to use typedef in dart | flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

when I used the **typedef** in the code it didn't do anything extra except increase my line of code.
**I need to know when to use typedef and when to avoid it?**

**Code snippet using typedef**

```
typedef SaySomething = void Function(String name);
    
    void sayHello(String name){
      print('Hello to $name');
    }
    
    void sayGoodbye(String name){
      print('Goodbye to $name');
    }
    
    void main() {
      // Using alias
      SaySomething myFunction;
      
      myFunction = sayHello;
      myFunction('mehran@kateintl.com');
      
      myFunction = sayGoodbye;
      myFunction('mehran@kateintl.com');
    }
```

**Code snippet without using typedef**

```
void sayHello(String name){print('Hello to $name');}
        
        void sayGoodbye(String name){ print('Goodbye to $name');}
        
        void main() {        
          sayHello('mehran@kateintl.com');            
          sayGoodbye('mehran@kateintl.com');
        }
```

Comment: A `typedef` is a type alias intended to be a convenience to make code more readable.  You never *need* to use it.

Comment: @jamesdlin  please provide a brief explanation  Thanks

Comment: What's to explain? You're never forced to use it. You always can type out the full type name instead of the shorter alias if you really want.  Now, if you instead want to ask when would `typdef`s be preferred, that's a different question.  Have you read https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#typedefs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it is my belief that there are very few situations in which you need `typedef`, but it can help to avoid long code repetition, take a look at this example class:

```
class MyClass {
  MyClass(this.value, {
    this.onChange,
    this.onSubmit,
    this.onCancel,
    this.onDelete,
    this.onReset,
  });

  Map<String, Map<int, List<double>>> value;
  
  void Function(Map<String, Map<int, List<double>>>)? onChange;
  void Function(Map<String, Map<int, List<double>>>)? onSubmit;
  void Function(Map<String, Map<int, List<double>>>)? onCancel;
  void Function(Map<String, Map<int, List<double>>>)? onDelete;
  void Function(Map<String, Map<int, List<double>>>)? onReset;
}
```

The above code is ugly to say the least, I think it is obvious how to use typedef here, but I will show it nonetheless.

```
typedef MyCallback = void Function(Map<String, Map<int, List<double>>>);

class MyClass {
  MyClass(this.value, {
    this.onChange,
    this.onSubmit,
    this.onCancel,
    this.onDelete,
    this.onReset,
  });

  Map<String, Map<int, List<double>>> value;

  MyCallback? onChange;
  MyCallback? onSubmit;
  MyCallback? onCancel;
  MyCallback? onDelete;
  MyCallback? onReset;
}
```

or even

```
typedef MyClassValue = Map<String, Map<int, List<double>>>;

class MyClass {
  MyClass(this.value, {
    this.onChange,
    this.onSubmit,
    this.onCancel,
    this.onDelete,
    this.onReset,
  });

  MyClassValue value;

  void Function(MyClassValue)? onChange;
  void Function(MyClassValue)? onSubmit;
  void Function(MyClassValue)? onCancel;
  void Function(MyClassValue)? onDelete;
  void Function(MyClassValue)? onReset;
}
```

Yes, it is more code, but the code is better looking.

In general, `typedef` is suited for functional programming patterns where you find yourself passing functions as arguments and returning functions from functions.

Comment: Yes,  You are right! but is this the only reason for using typedef?

Comment: I believe it is, of course I can't be sure, but I have not found any other use cases besides this one, [the docs](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#typedefs) weren't much help either.

Comment: yes, you are right! Thanks